# Lookup max and timestamp values within X hours

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to use Excel's Max function to return the max number in range of numbers within 2 hours from my start time and then return the exact time that max occurred.

I figured out the max value between the timestamp and 2 hours afterwards.

```
=MAXIFS($B:$B,$A:$A,"<="&D2+TIME(2,0,0),$A:$A,">="&D2)
=MAXIFS($B:$B,$A:$A,"<="&D3+TIME(2,0,0),$A:$A,">="&D3)
etc.
```

However, I am struggling to find the datevalue timestamp (Column F) that this max occurred (within that 2 hour window). I tried Index/match but it's not returning the timestamp in that 2 hour window that the max value occurred (it returns timestamps corresponding to those numbers well outside the 2 hour window). Any thoughts?

Here is the Index Match formula I tried that breaks when it gets to F6

```
=INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(E6,$B:$B,0))
```

I believe it needs the same logic as the MAXIFS formula so that it is only matching on values on Column B such that their corresponding timestamp (Column A) is within the timestamp from {Column D, Column D + 2 hours}

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Could you post a trimmed-down version of your Excel file so we can play with it directly? I suggest to remove all information that is not needed for your question.

Comment: Thank you! Just attached it. Couldn't figure out where to attach an excel file so I took a photo of a few rows.

Comment: @delphi, you mean to say that for example you want to find Date from column A or D, match with E2 downwards ? If yes for me Index Match is working,, what error U r finding,,, or may be U r not apply Date Time format on Col F.

Comment: Column E has the maxifs formula I typed above. I want to find out the date that value occurred (it occurs in Column B) from Column A. It is problematic because Index Match doesn't work in F6 because it returns 2/17/20 21:45 instead of the correct answer of 2/18/20

Comment: I just updated the screenshot and details in the question to include the Index Match I tried and a bit more detail.

Comment: Could you edit your question and paste the data from columns A, B and D into a code-block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the FILTER function.

I recreated some of your data and formatted both datasets as Tables. I also put the allowable hours difference in cell E1 and named that cell within_hours.

[image]

To make things simpler, I added a column called "LatestAllowableTime", which has this formula:

```
=[@Timevalue]+TIME(within_hours,0,0)
```

To get the maximum value between the start and allowed end is exactly how you said - using MAXIFS.

```
=MAXIFS(dataset1[Value],dataset1[Timevalue],"<=" & [@LatestAllowedTime],dataset1[Timevalue],">=" & [@Timevalue])
```

You can filter dataset1 using some criteria by using the FILTER function. To use multiple AND conditions in the second parameter of the FILTER function, you wrap each condition in parentheses and put an asterisk between them. So, the filter to get the timevalues from dataset1 based on the value in the column MaxValueWithinXHours is:

```
=FILTER(dataset1[Timevalue],(dataset1[Value]=[@MaxValueWithinXHours])*(dataset1[Timevalue]<=[@LatestAllowedTime])*(dataset1[Timevalue]>=[@Timevalue]))
```

You'll notice that for value=91, the #SPILL! message is displayed. That's because there is more than 1 row between the start and end times with that value. Those rows are colored green in my screenshot.

So, to pick one of those timevalues, we can use either MIN or MAX. It looks from your screenshot that you want MIN (i.e. the row with 91 in the 2 hour period with the earliest time):

```
=MIN(FILTER(dataset1[Timevalue],(dataset1[Value]=[@MaxValueWithinXHours])*(dataset1[Timevalue]<=[@LatestAllowedTime])*(dataset1[Timevalue]>=[@Timevalue])))
```

I think that does it.

EDIT:

You might have better performance with PowerQuery. Create two connections to each of the tables - dataset1 (the list you want to return values from) and dataset2 (the list you want to return values for). For dataset2, I just kept the first 2 columns in the original screenshot above. To create a query, select a cell in your table and choose 'Data > Get & Transform > From Table/Range'.

For the Query dataset2, I added an Index column to make it easier to see what was going on. In the Power Query Editor, I selected 'Add Column > Index Column' to do that. I then moved that index column to the left. That gave me this:

[image]

After making sure that all my date/time columns were of the correct type, I added a Custom Column to dataset2, configured like this:

[image]

The formula:

```
let x = [StartTime], y = [LatestAllowedTime] in Table.SelectRows(dataset1,each[TimeValue] >= x and [TimeValue] <= y)
```

The Table.SelectRows was easy enough to find, but the tricky part which needed some digging (ultimately I got the hint [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/power-query-table-selectrows-where-each-condition-is-not-a-constant.909697/)) was that I had to store values from the current row in dataset2 in variables before being able to use them inside the Table.SelectRows function.

The idea of this formula is to use the values from the current row to filter and return a set of rows from dataset1 whose Timevalue is between the StartTime and the LatestAllowedTime. Actually it took a while to figure out, but it was a learning experience!

After expanding the rows returned by the formula, I got this:

[image]

Progress! Finally got the right rows from dataset1 into the query.

Next, to get the max value from each Index in dataset2.

To do that, I duplicated dataset2 and called it dataset2_grouped. I then used Group By from the Transform tab, configured like this:

[image]

That gave me this result:

[image]

Those are the correct max values. Now I just need to get the right dataset1[TimeValue]. To do that, I just use 'Home > Merge Queries > Merge Queries as New', configured like this:

[image]

The results after removing the 'dataset2_grouped' column, which we don't need:

[image]

The last step is to get the row from each index that has the minimum value in dataset1rows.TimeValue:

[image]

After clicking OK on the Group By and then 'Home > Close & Load', we get the right results:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This works but it's taking forever whenever I update LatestAllowableTime (>30 seconds) or anything else on the spreadsheet for that matter. My spreadsheet is 600 rows and will ultimately be 10x longer than that shortly.

Comment: The issue here is that there can be multiple rows with the same value in dataset1 within the allowed timeframe. Because of that, you have to use FILTER, which is an array function. This means that every row in dataset2 has an array attached to it. 

They are probably other ways to achieve what you want (PowerQuery, for example), but without more context, it's difficult to say.

Comment: Thank you. It does work it's just too slow. Is there another formula that would work for this that is faster?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**How it works:**

- An array (CSE) formulain Cell W2:

  ```
  {=MAX(IF((T$2:T$11>=V2)*(T$2:T$11<=V2+TIME(2,0,0)),U$2:U$11,0))}
  ```
- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.
- Lookup formula in Cell X2:

  `=IFERROR(INDEX(T$2:T$11,MATCH(W2,U$2:U$11,0)),"")`

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have these formulas in my answer already and unfortunately the Index Match version does not answer my question successfully. It breaks in F6 in my table in that it lists the wrong date.